# How to return dynamic object from operator function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation, return-type

I am quite confused about this. How to return a dynamically allocated object from operator function? 
Consider following example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "vld.h"
using std::cout;
class Point
{
    public:
    Point(int x,int y) : a(x),b(y)
    { }
    Point()
    { }
    Point operator + (Point p)
    {
        Point* temp=new Point();
        temp->a=a+p.a;
        temp->b=b+p.b;
        Point p1(*temp);  // construct p1 from temp
        delete temp;      // deallocate temp
        return p1;
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<a<<' '<<b<<'\n';
    }
    private:
        int a,b;
};
int main()
{
    Point* p1=new Point(3,6);
    Point* p2=new Point(3,6);
    Point* p3=new Point();
    *p3=*p2+*p1;
    p3->show();
    VLDEnable();
    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    delete p3;
    VLDReportLeaks();
    system("pause");
}
```

Can I write this program without extra object p1 in this case in overloaded operator + function? How Can I directly return temp?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Please help me.

Comment: Don't. Just instantiate a `Point` and return it. There is no reason to dynamically allocate. Anywhere in your code.

Comment: @juanchopanza: yes, I know that  it is fine to just  instantiate a Point and return it. But I want to know that how can I do the same for dynamic objects?

Comment: @meet: You wouldn't overload value-based operators to handle dynamic objects, since that would be massively confusing and error-prone. Write sensibly-named functions to work with references and/or smart pointers if you don't want value semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are a bit confused between Java syntax and C++. In C++, there is no need for `new` unless you want your objects to be dynamically allocated (on the heap). Just use

```
Point temp; // define the variable
// process it
return temp;
```

In this way, your local objects will be created on the stack, and you won't have to care about forgetting to `delete` them etc.

Returning a pointer from `operator+` is wrong

```
Point* operator + (Point p) 
{ 
    Point* tmp = new Point;
    // process
    return tmp; // return the pointer to the dynamically-allocated object
}
```

It actually breaks the `operator+`, since you won't be able to chain it, i.e. `a+b+c` won't work anymore.
That's because `a + b` returns a pointer, then `a + b + c` tries invoking `operator+` on a pointer, for which is not defined. Also, there are more serious issues, like leaking memory during the construction of your temporary objects in assignments, see @Barry's comment below. So I hope I have convinced you to return the object and not a pointer to it.

Comment: yes, I know Point temp; is an automatic object but I want to dynamically allocate the object & return it. Please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: @meet No, you don't want to dynamically allocate the object.

Comment: @meet see the edit, but you really don't want to do that, and you shouldn't (objects on the stack are faster than the ones on the heap, so be happy that C++ doesn't enforce you to use dynamically-allocated objects).

Comment: @meet If you did, `*p3=*p2+*p1;` wouldn't compile, you'd have to do `*p3 = *(*p2 + *p1);`, which would then leak memory.

Comment: @Barry: yes, it failed in compilation? Why? Will you please explain this little scary syntax *p3 = *(*p2 + *p1); ? Why it would leak memory?

Comment: @Barry and chaining will be a nightmare

Comment: @vsoftco: will you edit your answer to explain why it breaks operator+? Why I won't be able to chain it?

Comment: @meet, `(*p2 + *p1`) is equivalent to `*p2.operator+(*p1)`, which will then return a pointer to some allocated memory. You then dereference the pointer, `*(*p2 + *p1)`, and copy the object to `*p3`. Hence, your initial allocated memory is lost.

Comment: @meet see the updated edit. Hope it clarifies it. Pointers are a bit tricky, especially the memory management aspect of them. Whenever you create temporary dynamically allocated objects via pointers, if you don's store a pointer to that temporary object, you'll leak memory since no one will invoke a `delete` on it.

Comment: @vsoftco: +1 for good explanation. I understood. so, that's why C++ programmer should minimize use of new. right?

Comment: @meet Yes, use if possible smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`, but again, only when needed. For many tasks you don't need pointers, and if you don't need them, you shouldn't use them (even if you can).

Comment: I do not like this answer. It is misleading (If the reader omits the 'footprints')

Comment: @DieterLücking What exactly is it misleading? Let me know so I can correct it.

Comment: You should discourage from 'If you really want ...' (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199249/when-should-i-return-pointer-to-object-not-an-object-from-the-operator-functio/30199386#30199249)

Comment: @DieterLücking Modified, you are right, one shouldn't give advice how to do it "the wrong way" :) Thanks for the comment.