# When should I return pointer to object (not an object) from the operator function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-type

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166644/how-to-return-dynamic-object-from-operator-function). I understood that it returning pointer to object can result memory leak, also because of raw pointers they are error prone, also tricky. So,number of peoples advised me to not return pointer to an object from operator function. So,I am convinced to return object from operator function. But I am curious to know that are there any circumstances exist when returning pointer to an object from overloaded operator function is fine & desirable?

If your answer is yes, please justify the answer using suitable example.

Please help me.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Downvoters: Why downvotes? What's wrong with question?

Comment: operators should either return by reference for operator chaining or by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a bad example. Short answer: never(!) return a pointer from a binary function (operator). Return by value or a std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr.

Note: The accepted answer in the link of the question changed afterward.

Comment: Lucking: So, which is the good example when returning pointer to an object is fine & causes no problems?

Comment: @meet No allocated pointer is (especially, if operators are involved)